# How to Put Data coming through Request or session into JavaScript Code in a JSP Page

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, jsp

I am making a Project where the need is to query no of already booked seats from database and show those seats as already booked in the layout made on a JSP page using JavaScript.
I have made a query in database & I have the data. All the data is joined by "," using `Join()` function.

`Example:- 3,6,8,10`

Now how to put that data dynamically into Javscript code existing on a JSP Page? The Javascript Code where I want to put the dynamic data (Not Posting Full Java Script Code, Posting Only The Exact Part)

```
<script>
        var bookedSeat = [5,10,25];  // << Put Dynamic Data Here
        seats(bookedSeat);
    </script>
```

I have tried using `<% --- %>` but it didn't work. Can someone please help me? I am very new to JavaScript.

Comment: Can you show your `Servlet` code where you are setting the variable you want to print?

Comment: So you want to search something from database and put it in to jscript array and display in a div or text field right? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use those `Request` or `Session` data in JavaScript using `EL`. You can try like below code:

```
<script>
    var bookedSeat = ${variableName};  //Put variable name which you are setting in request or session
    seats(bookedSeat);
</script>
```